# gitlab push fail with error 'bad object refs/pipelines/***'

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm posting this question because googling *gitlab  bad object refs/pipelines/* found no similiar pages, and I think it is interesting to investigate.

There's no stable and minimal reproducible steps, just describe what happend. I have(the owner) a repo and with only **single** branch `main`, add has `.gitlab-ci.yml` to enable pipelines. Never added any pre or post hooks. Mainly use *git for windows* built in *bash* or *git gui* to pull and push. Everything goes smoothly until one day push got error like

```
Pushing to git.labs.hosting.of.mycompany:myrepo.git
remote: fatal: bad object refs/pipelines/2651688
fatal: bad object refs/pipelines/2651688
To git.labs.hosting.of.mycompany:myrepo.git
  ![remote rejected] main -> main (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git.labs.hosting.of.mycompany:myrepo.git'
```

The number `2651688` is the one of the most recent(not last one, and successful) pipelines of this repo. To my limited git knowledge, **refs** should mean something like *branch*, but I never create branch name like that. So I thought the repo state corrupted when running ci.

Tried cloning the repo to another folder and push directly, same issue. so seems not client side issue. Also tried push another repo in same group, no problem.

There's no special jobs changing the repo itself. By running `git ls-remote` for this problematic repo got many `refs/keep-around/*`, still don't see refs/pipelines/*

```bash
3ef2b1aba9f1493a039c18c978ae192143363ee6        HEAD
3ef2b1aba9f1493a039c18c978ae192143363ee6        refs/heads/main
064e56e78a6679ec570ad506e0b2f861dbada059        refs/keep-around/064e56e78a6679ec570ad506e0b2f861dbada059
...tens of refs/keep-around/*
```

Could anyone explain why this issue happens and could it be solved from client side? I'm not the gitlab owner so cannot do anything on server side repo directly. After a random [housekeeping](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html), i can push now. so i cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: As a general rule: prefer pasting *text* over *images*. For a terminal window: you can easily select the content of the window, paste it in a text editor to remove the elements you don't want (e.g: search & replace the path prefix you want to hide) and paste that text in your question.

Comment: your second screenshot shows a succesful push. Is this the one you wanted to show ?

Comment: it is only to demonstrate i have correct client setup, for comparison.

Comment: i've updated with only text and removed the correct push one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `git push`, the lines pefixed with a `remote:`  indicate they are executed on the server side, as part of a `pre-receive` hook for example. I'm not familiar enough with the standard actions run through a `.gitlab-ci.yml`, but I would say your first push happened at a moment when the remote repo wasn't in sync with some other gitlab data.

---

- is this error persistent ? or does it go away with time ?
- does it go away if you manually launch a new gitlab CI job, then run a `git push` ?

(these two questions would point to some issue with how the repo used by gitlab's jobs is synced with gitlab's data)

- on your local clone: if you run `git ls-remote`, do you see references named `refs/pipelines/...` ?

do check the documentation for the actions you trigger from your `.gitlab.yml`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have used gitlab ci for at least 2 years, should be familiar enough. and never experience this issue. just updated the question with contents of `git ls-remote`. any ideas? this error persists. however, when today i randomly did a [housekeeping](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html), i can push now. so i cannot reproduce the issue or do more investigating now.